# passport send error by json

Tags: json, angularjs, node.js, passport.js

I'm making an app with express + passport and angularJS; I want to be able to send any errors produced from passport (such as username taken or no email provided) by json so my angularJS app can receive these errors in a json response. More specifically right now I want to have a json response to my signup POST method that outputs any errors. I have tried to do this for myself and I've search all over the web and stack overflow I just cannot work this out!

Here is my users route file in express:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var isAuthenticated = require('../config/isAuthenticated');

module.exports = function(passport){
    router.get('/loggedin', function(req, res){
        res.send(req.isAuthenticated() ? req.user : '0');

    });

    router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
        successRedirect : '/',
        failureRedirect : '/signup',
        failureFlash: true
    }));

    router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login'), function(req, res){
        res.send(req.user);
    });


    router.post('/signout', function(req,res){
        req.logout();
        res.json({redirect: '/'});
    });

    router.get('/authtest', isAuthenticated, function(req, res){
        res.render('authtest', {user: req.user});
    });

    return router;
};
```

This is my passport signup strategy:

```
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'username',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true
},
function(req, username, password, done){
    process.nextTick(function(){
        User.findOne({'local.username' : username}, function(err, user){
            if(err) return done(err); 
            if (user) { //username already exists
                return done(null, false, {message: 'Username already exists'});     
            } else if(!req.body.email) { //no email address provided
                return done(null, false, {message: 'You must provide an email address!'});
            } else {
                var newUser = new User();
                newUser.local.username = username;
                newUser.generateHash(password, function(err, hash){
                    if(err) return done(err);
                    newUser.local.password = hash;
                });
                newUser.email = req.body.email;
                newUser.servers = [];
                newUser.save(function(err){
                    if(err) throw err;
                    return done(null, newUser);
                }); 
            };
        });
    });
}
));
```

I know looking at my code right now it looks like I haven't tried to solve this myself at all but this is just my latest working code; I have been stuck at this for the past few days!

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

According to the current code of passport this is probably achievable by passing custom callback to handle all results of authentiction yourself. This callback is given after options or instead of those.

```
passport( "local-signup", { ... }, callbackFn );
```

or

```
passport( "local-login", callbackFn );
```

This callback is used in **all resulting situations** of trying to authenticae. It is thus invoked on processing errors like this:

```
callbackFn( err )
```

If (all configured) authentications have failed it is called with

```
callbackFn( null, false, challenge(s), status(es) )
```

On successfully having authenticated user the callback is invoked like so:

```
callbackFn( null, user, infos )
```

with `infos` optionally provided by strategies.

**Now comes the bottom-side:** In *either* situation `passport.authenticate()` skips usual processing but instantly invokes provided callback to care for the rest. This includes processing of any options passed in call for `passport.authenticate()` like flashing messages, preparing session and request for containing authenticated user etc.

1. Since options given `passport.authenticate()` are never passed into callback there is actually no obvious reason to use both.
2. When I was stumbling over the very same problem (linking passport-service with angular-js POST request) I declined to consider use of callback a proper solution. This callback isn't documented. And it doesn't even look quite useful for it isn't passing `req`, `res` and `next` to pass any actual request in callback. Thus it makes very little sense to use it at all and I'd expect it to vanish soon or to change its behaviour quite much.

So the second approach was about trying to figure out why there is a problem in AngularJS. Passport is sending plain text `Unauthorized` in response with status code `401`. AngularJS is trying to parse this as JSON and produces Syntax error. The text `Unauthorized` results from passprt ending response very simply by invoking

```
res.statusCode = 401;
res.end(http.STATUS_CODES[res.statusCode]);
```

Thus a proper *workaround* might try to replace

1. either text in `http.STATUS_CODES` though this is having impact on processing further requests and thus isn't preferrable
2. or `res.end()` by an overloaded method acting differently if `res.statusCode` is 401.

Due to affecting any current request, only, I tried the latter. Replaced `res.end()` might be used to send any text you want:

```js
router.post('/login',
  function(req, res, next) {
    var _end = res.end;
    res.end = function() {
      if (res.statusCode === 401) {
        return _end('{"status":"Unauthorized"}');
      }
      return _end.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    next();
  },
  passport.authenticate('local-login'),
  function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.user);
  }
);
```

Alternatively the replaced method might add previously missing response header information on content type, for this was actually causing issues in AngularJS processing that response as JSON *by default*.

```js
router.post('/login',
  function(req, res, next) {
    var _end = res.end;
    res.end = function() {
      if (res.statusCode === 401) {
        res.set("Content-Type", "text/plain");
      }
      return _end.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    next();
  },
  passport.authenticate('local-login'),
  function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.user);
  }
);
```

Finally, either approach is really just a workaround. I think passport is in the need for revising this annoying limitation.